# C#, ASP.NET: how to get a confirm message box from server side code when a condition is met

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button in my page which is used to save data of gridview which is dynamically populated. Before saving I want to check some condition. The javascript function is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("This will completely delete the project. Are you sure?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            }
            else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    </script>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="lnkBtn" onClick="lnkBtn_Click" onClientClick="Confirm()"></button>
```

The code behind is as follows:

```
protected void lnkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str=gdView.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Text;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtID = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gdView.Rows[0].Cells[8].FindControl(str);
            if (txtID.Text != "")
            {
                string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
                if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                {
                    MyAlert("Yes clicked");
                }
                else
                {
                    MyAlert("No clicked");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MyAlert("No Text found.");
            }
        }
```

Now the problem is since I have the function Confirm() in the onClientClick event, the confirm dialog appears the moment the user clicks the button, instead it should appear only when a string is found in txtID.
I tried to modify the code by removing the onClientClick event as follows:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="lnkBtn" onClick="lnkBtn_Click" ></button>
protected void lnkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str=gdView.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Text;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtID = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gdView.Rows[0].Cells[8].FindControl(str);

            if (txtID.Text != "")
            {

                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "confirm", "Confirm();", true);
                string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];

                if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                {
                    MyAlert("Yes clicked");
                }
                else
                if (confirmValue == "No")
                {
                    MyAlert("No clicked");
                }
            }
        }
```

Here also it is not working properly. The confirmValue is getting the value but using it only during the subsequent click of the button. It is not passing value stored during the present click event instead the previously stored value is passed to if block. Please help to find what should I do get it right.
Thanks.

Comment: why not check txtID value in confirm method in javascript ?

Comment: use ajax on button click and handle any validation on server side, based on  condition return some true, false and show message at client side.